# Selecting specific excel rows for analysis in pandas/ipython?

Tags: python, pandas

This question is probably quite elementary, but I am totally stuck here so I would appreciate any help: Is there a way to extract data for analysis from an excel file by selecting specific row numbers? For example, if I have an excel file with 30 rows, and I want to add up the values of row 5+10+21+27 ?

I only managed to learn how to select adjacent ranges with the iloc function like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsl")

df.iloc[1:5]
```

If this is not possible in Pandas, I would appreciate advice how to copy selected rows from a spreadsheet into a new spreadsheet via openpyxl, then I could just load the new worksheet into Pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do like so, passing a list of indices:

```
df.iloc[[4,9,20,26]].sum()
```

Mind that pyton uses 0-indexing, so these indices are one below the desired row numbers.

Comment: Thanks, thats what I was looking for! The double braces are the trick, when I used iloc.[4,9] it did a row+column combination.

Comment: It is probably better practice to be explicit about which row is being indexed. For example, you could say `df.iloc[[4,9,20,26],:]` indicating which dimension you are indexing. Helps avoid misunderstandings and inadvertent wrong results, too.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel("example.xlsx")   
sum(df.data[i - 1] for i in [5, 10, 21, 27])
```

My df:

```
    data
0      1
1      2
2      3
3      4
4      5
...
```